# How do i send multiple arraylist from controller to ajax success function

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have multiple individual arrayList's in my spring controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteFileFromS31")
public  @ResponseBody List<String> deleteFileFromS3(){
ArrayList<String> l1=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> l2=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> l3=new ArrayList<String>();   
}
```

how do i get those individual arraylist's in ajax success function

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return a `List<List<String>>` to get an array of arrays in json but you won't have the names and you'll have to be based on the order:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello")
    public List<List<String>> path() {
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("l11","l12","l13");
        List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("l21","l22","l23");
        List<String> l3 = Arrays.asList("l31","l32","l33");
        return Arrays.asList(l1,l2,l3);
    }
}
```

> Result: [["l11","l12","l13"],["l21","l22","l23"],["l31","l32","l33"]]

or alternatively create a DTO encapsulating these and return it directly to get a json object including the param names:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello")
    public DTO path() {
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("l11","l12","l13");
        List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("l21","l22","l23");
        List<String> l3 = Arrays.asList("l31","l32","l33");
        return new DTO(l1,l2,l3);
    }

    public static class DTO {
        private final List<String> l1;
        private final List<String> l2;
        private final List<String> l3;

        public DTO(List<String> l1, List<String> l2, List<String> l3) {
            this.l1 = l1;
            this.l2 = l2;
            this.l3 = l3;
        }

        public List<String> getL1() {
            return l1;
        }

        public List<String> getL2() {
            return l2;
        }

        public List<String> getL3() {
            return l3;
        }
    }
}
```

> Result:
>   {"l1":["l11","l12","l13"],"l2":["l21","l22","l23"],"l3":["l31","l32","l33"]}

Comment: How can i  retrieve in ajax success function

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and put the ArrayLists inside it and than you return this class in the controller.

```
public class ClassName {
   List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
   List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
   List<String> l3 = new ArrayList<>();

   // Getters and Setters
}



public @ResponseBody ClassName deleteFileFromS3(){ 
    ClassName lists = new ClassName();
    // set lists
    return lists;
}
```